# Перекрытие текста тенью (пример по ссылке)

Tags: css3, jquery, html, css, javascript

[link text](http://piccy.info/view3/6494017/1d0bf399db8f8004a2ca3740b42f5cad/)

Comment: Картинку наложите с градиентом (opacity 100 - 0);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/copist/m9yfB/

Обратите внимание на эти строки:

```
/* у блока есть размер, обрезание текста если не входит в размер и относительная позиция */
.block div.desc { width: 244px; height: 50px; float: left; position: relative; overflow: hidden; }
/* у блока есть заливка картинкой, размер и абсолютная позиция, привязка справа */
.block div.desc em { display: block; position: absolute; right: 0px; width: 30px; height: 50px;  z-index: 2; background: url("полупрозрачная-картинка.png") repeat-y; }
```

Для тени понадобится полупрозрачная картинка, делается так: слой белого цвета с маской прозрачности, в которой прозрачность меняется от 100% до 0% по линейному градиенту. Например, так: http://take.ms/zk5Cp